# where clause to search values from multiple column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have the sql server table with 51 columns like below

id
remarks1
remarks2
.
.
.
remarks50

I need to search if particular string is present in atleast one remarks field like in the example below

```
id  remarks1  remarks2   remarks3  remarks4
1   key       nonkey      grabaze   jjjjj
2   uuu       888          8888     kkk
3   888       key          hjhj      kjkj
```

suppose i need to search `key` which is present in either remarks1,2,3.....or 50

I can have sql like

```
select id from tbl where remarks1 ='key' or remarks2='key' and so on ..
```

writing or query upto 50 columns is really unpractical.. do we have any quick method?

Comment: This might help - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b8989cd2-9792-45eb-b6bf-cd998f141eea/how-to-check-multiple-column-for-single-value

Comment: It's a sign of a poor table design. This ought to be a table with 3 columns, `id`, `<something>` and `remarks` and up to 50 rows for each `id`, where `<something>` contains the numbers from 1-50 which are currently embedded in your column names. Because it appears that logically, `remarks2` and `remarks45` ought to be treated the same, then they should actually be the same column.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using below stored procedure .

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_FindStringInTable @stringToFind VARCHAR(100), @schema sysname, @table sysname 
AS 

DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @where VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @columnName sysname 
DECLARE @cursor VARCHAR(8000) 

BEGIN TRY 
   SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @schema + '].[' + @table + '] WHERE' 
   SET @where = '' 

   SET @cursor = 'DECLARE col_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
   FROM ' + DB_NAME() + '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
   WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ''' + @schema + ''' 
   AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @table + ''' 
   AND DATA_TYPE IN (''char'',''nchar'',''ntext'',''nvarchar'',''text'',''varchar'')' 

   EXEC (@cursor) 

   OPEN col_cursor    
   FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor INTO @columnName    

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
   BEGIN    
       IF @where <> '' 
           SET @where = @where + ' OR' 

       SET @where = @where + ' [' + @columnName + '] LIKE ''' + @stringToFind + '''' 
       FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor INTO @columnName    
   END    

   CLOSE col_cursor    
   DEALLOCATE col_cursor  

   SET @sqlCommand = @sqlCommand + @where 
   --PRINT @sqlCommand 
   EXEC (@sqlCommand)  
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
   PRINT 'There was an error. Check to make sure object exists.' 
   IF CURSOR_STATUS('variable', 'col_cursor') <> -3 
   BEGIN 
       CLOSE col_cursor    
       DEALLOCATE col_cursor  
   END 
END CATCH
```

The stored procedure gets created in the master database so you can use it in any of your databases and it takes three parameters:

**stringToFind** - this is the string you are looking for.  This could be a simple value as 'test' or you can also use the % wildcard such as '%test%', '%test' or 'test%'.

**schema** - this is the schema owner of the object

**table** - this is the table name you want to search, the procedure will search all char, nchar, ntext, nvarchar, text and varchar columns in the table

[Source](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1522/searching-and-finding-a-string-value-in-all-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [unpivot](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to transpose the `remarks*` columns as rows with a common column name, which you can then filter on. (You'll need to repeat all 51 columns).
Distinct will be needed to eliminate cases where more than one column matches (i.e. to mimic the original `or`)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, Rmk
  FROM
    (SELECT ID, Remarks1, Remarks2, Remarks3, Remarks4
     FROM Remarks) r
     UNPIVOT
       (Rmk FOR RmkCol IN (Remarks1, Remarks2, Remarks3, Remarks4))AS unpvt
  WHERE rmk = 'key';
```

[Sql Fiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f3d52/20)

However I would advise you to reconsider normalising this into a 1 to many `Remarks` table - if your table is large, you will need a large number of indexes on the `Remark*` columns.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT remarks1, remarks2, remarks3, remarks4 from tabl_name
WHERE CONTAINS (( remarks1, remarks2, remarks3, remarks4),'888') ORDER BY id;